# Setting up groups in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, groups

I have been tasked with overhauling our SharePoint site's permissions. Currently tons of one off permissions have been granted and I am trying to get away from these and go the route of groups.

It is my understanding that a site, by default, has the site.members, site.visitors, and site.owners groups. I was going to create groups for each library, but this would be too tedious and decided to assign users into those groups which would cover the majority of users.

I was concerned about overlap at first. By that I mean Person X is in site.members, and they can view all subsites and libraries. This isn't that big of an issue now. However when I wanted to fine tune things a bit for a library I ran into an issue.

I have a group called printshop - full control. I created this group at our operations site level. I then went to the print shop library, added the group printshop - full control, and gave it Full Control permissions.

Now, when I look at this group, it says it has full control, limited access to the main site. How can I get around this. I only want the users to be able to have full control on that specific library.

Is this possible with groups?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list/library to have different permissions that the parent site, you have to break the inheritance on the permissions. Once broken, any changes made to the list/library permissions will affect only that list/library but it will also not receive any changes in permissions that are made at the site level.

Comment: Thank you. I had created the group at the parent level with no permissions. Then I added the group to the child set and gave it full control permissions. Even though I assigned the permissions at the child level, they roll up to the parent? Maybe I am misunderstanding. I didn't think I could make a group at the child level.

Comment: If you hadn't changed the permissions inheritance on your site and the print shop library inherits the permissions from the site still, when you added the group and at the site level it will automatically get added to the library permissions because it gets the permissions from the site.